# Calling parameterized constructor in createExecutableExtension

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've a class (`Clock`) with a parameterized constructor. I am calling this `Clock` class in a plugin using extensions.

```
try {
            for (IConfigurationElement e : config) {
                System.out.println("Harsha Evaluating extension of Clock");
                o = e.createExecutableExtension("class");
            }
        } catch (CoreException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }
```

The method `createExecutableExtenison` is only calling default constructor of `Clock` class. How can I call parameterized constructor of `Clock` class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to edit the code to `createExecutableExtension`. Can you do that? If you can, post the relevant code in that method so we can see it and help.

Comment: `createExecutableExtension` is a predefined method in `org.eclipse.core.runtime.IConfigurationElement`.    Do we really need to edit this method?

Comment: `createExecutableExtension` is part of a core Eclipse plugin so editing it is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc for `createExecutableExtension` says:

> The specified class is instantiated using its 0-argument public
>   constructor.

so you can't use a parameterized constructor.

You can make your class implement `IExecutableExtension` in which case the method:

```
public void setInitializationData(IConfigurationElement config, String propertyName, Object data) throws CoreException;
```

will be called straight after construction. This can be used to get extra information from the configuration element.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it. `Tetris` class is in plugin1. `Clock` class is in Plugin2. I am calling `createExecutableExtension` for `Clock` in `Tetris` class. `Clock` class has parameterized constructor. How can I make sure that the parameterized constructor to be called automatically?

Comment: You **cannot** call a parameterized constructor using createExecutableExtension, you will have to do things a different way.